# Migração de site com bastante conteúdo

Tags: php, html

Eu estou migrando um site de 5gb de um servidor windows para um linux.
Antes de tudo estou baixando os arquivos que estão online via FTP para deixar um backup no meu computador.
Porém esse método está demorando muito.
Alguém sabe um jeito mais rápido de fazer o download dos arquivos?

Comment: Não. É assim mesmo. Se estiver usando o FileZilla, clique sobre o Servidor que está na lista de transferência e altere sua Prioridade para **Alta**. É o máximo que se pode fazer.

Comment: Será que não da para compactar isso e descompactar no local correto?..